# Intellij handling domain models

Tags: java, intellij-idea, model

I'm currently working on a project with Java in IntellJ, where different projects need the same model classes. This could be for example a Spring-application and a desktop application, which both need a model "Student".

Does anyone has an idea about a "best-practice-approach" on how to handle the class "Student" in IntelliJ, so that both projects (the Spring and the desktop application) have access to the class "Student"?

I know there are modules which can depend on each other. However, I'd prefer to have the Spring and the desktop application in their own git-repositories. Since the models will change often during development, I also don't like the idea of building a JAR first or import it over a private Maven dependency.

Any experiences?

Comment: Create a maven project for the model classes and import it as a dependency in other projects. Either locally, or by deploying the model jar to a remote repo.

Comment: @Bajal: is there a way of automating this process, so I don't have to manually rebuild the jar every time, the model changes?

Comment: If you have a CI/CD pipeline, you can put commit hooks to do the rebuild . This is what we do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three projects, one for the server, one for the client, and one for the shared libraries. The `Student` java class will go in the shared libraries and will be built and distributed as a jar. The other two projects must have dependencies on that jar.

To enable rapid development, you then want to create a parent pom, one level above these three projects, that aggregates them as modules into a single project. This allows you to update all three projects as if they were one in intellij, even though the dependency is really upon a jar. It is this parent pom you want to load into intellij.

Maven will then take care of the dependencies at release time -- the jar will be built first, then the client projects (in any order). This should only really be called from CI.